# Can Delphi applications have double shortcut keys like Visual Studio? (ie. Ctrl-k Ctrl-k)

Tags: delphi, vcl, shortcut

As stated in the title, I need double shortcut keys for my application (ie. as **Ctrl-k Ctrl-k** is the Toggle Bookmark key in VS.NET ). I wonder if any of you has found a solution for this in Delphi? I suspect by modifying the very core of VCL one might do but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SynEdit](http://synedit.sourceforge.net/) had/has this functionality in the SynEditKey*.* files (I'm looking at version 1.03 myself), complete with an editor for shortcuts.  Maybe you can not simply integrate them into your application, but the code will hopefully provide some guidance.